# Get next available date from start date and end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want available dates from database table.

```
Room number Start_date  End_date
room 1  2018-12-01  2018-12-05
room 1  2018-12-08  2018-12-15
room 1  2018-12-20  2018-12-31
```

Here is I added table from database.
When user select start date and end date than check in database. If already in between date of start date and end date then result want available date.

User start date = `2018-12-05`

End date = `2018-12-20`

Need result:

```
2018-12-06
2018-12-07
2018-12-16
2018-12-17
2018-12-18
2018-12-19
```

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: i want to get available dates in between user selected dates for room 1

Answer (score 1):

To really solve this problem, you need a `Calendar` table with one row per day.

With such a table, you can do:

```
select c.date
from calendar c
where c.date >= '2018-12-05' and
      c.date <= '2018-12-20' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where c.date >= start_date and
                        c.date <= end_date
                 );
```

I note that this does not take `room_number` into account at all -- because your question does not mention that at all.  If you have a question that involves `room_number`, ask *another* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you want to accomplish.